# My SQL INSERT not working in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My sql is not allowing me to insert the data. It used to work but I think I accidentally changed something in the code below. The error that is returned is: "Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'home', '111-333-111', '2', '2', '1')' at line 2"
Here is the PHP / SQL code:

```html
$house = $_GET['houseid'];
//connect to DB
$servername = "localhost";
$dusername = "root";
$dpassword = "Think";
$dbname= "realstate";

$id = $_SESSION['userid'];

//define home property variables
$data_province = $_POST["province"];
$data_country = $_POST["country"];
$data_city = $_POST["city"];
$data_type = $_POST["proptype"];
$data_bedroom = $_POST["bedroomnumb"];
$data_bathroom = $_POST["bathnumb"];
$data_community = $_POST["community"];
$data_price1 = $_POST["price1"];
$data_price2 = $_POST["price2"];
$data_price3 = $_POST["price3"];
$data_price = $data_price1 . "-" . $data_price2 . "-" . $data_price3;
$data_street = $_POST["street"];
$data_number = $_POST["number"];
if (isset ($_POST["furnished"])){
$data_furnished = 1;
} else {
$data_furnished = 0;
}
if (empty($data_province) || empty($data_country) || empty($data_city) || empty($data_type) || empty($data_bedroom) || empty($data_bathroom) || empty($data_community) || empty($data_price) || 
    empty($data_street) || empty ($data_number)){
    header('Location: /~ideen/sites/realestate/createproperty.php?errorfillall');

}
    
    // Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($realstate, $dusername, $dpassword, $dbname);



$insertdata = "INSERT INTO Porperties (Country, Province, City, Community, Street, Number, Type, Price, Bathnumb, Bednumb, Furnished)
VALUES('$data_country', '$data_province', '$data_city', '$data_community', '$data_street', '$data_number, '$data_type', '$data_price', '$data_bathroom', '$data_bedroom', '$data_furnished')";

    

if ($conn->query($insertdata) === TRUE) {
   $last_id = $conn->insert_id;
    $filenumero = $last_id;
    echo "SQL succes";
```

Comment: missing quote, I'll let you find it

Comment: Missing a quote, on `'$data_number`. Also, this code is viable to SQL injection, best to use mysqli or PDO. Last but not least, when using `header()` follow with `exit()` or `die()` unless you want to continue the code below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a closing quotation mark after `$data_number` in the sql statement:

```
...'$data_number', '$data_type'...
```

Comment: Ohh sorry u won that... didnt cheked the answer. Earn my vote for eagle eye